# Cloth Simulation deforms before hitting anything, and seems to pass right through the table and plate

Tags: modeling, animation, cloth-simulation

[image: Cloth Simulation]

I've just started learning animation in Blender, and I've come across a problem with the cloth simulation. In the attached picture, I made a table, a plate, and a piece of cloth. The cloth is simply a plane with 50 subdivisions, and I turned on cloth simulation and self collisions. I added the collision modifier to both the table and the plate. When I run the simulation, the cloth deforms before hitting anything, and seems to pass right through the table and plate. Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to play around with the settings in the cloth physics. As for the table, you need to make it a *Rigid Body* > *Passive* type, in the physics tab for the cloth to collide with it. The same goes for the plate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, [including a .blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file) or a minimal working example script would be ideal because then we can directly diagnose any potential issues.

In lieu of that, here is a minimal working example script using Blender 2.82a with cloth collisions, which you can build upon for your own tests.

If this script is in a file called `test.py` then you just have to run `blender -P test.py` from your command line (e.g., this is usually Terminal or iTerm if you're on a Mac OS). Then this will open up Blender, and you can play around with the settings and observe what modifiers need to be present.

```
import bpy

def clear_scene():
    """Get rid of the starting cube."""
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

def make_meshes():
    """Make Suzanne mesh, with the collision modifier."""
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(2, 2, 2))
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='COLLISION')

def make_fabrics():
    """Make fabric that drops over the Suzanne mesh and collides with it."""
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(3.5, 3.5, 3.5))
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, 6.0))

    # Sub-divide into 50, like how you did it.
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=50)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CLOTH')

    # Turn on collisions an increase the quality of the steps.
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Cloth"].settings.quality = 10
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Cloth"].collision_settings.collision_quality = 5
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Cloth"].collision_settings.use_self_collision = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear_scene()
    make_meshes()
    make_fabrics()
```

A few additional comments about the code:

- It deletes the starting cube and adds a Suzanne mesh. I figured this would be more interesting, and it also shows how you need to add the collision modifier.
- The cloth is subdivided into 50 (like you did) with the collisions on.

Upon running the code, I end up with the following screen recording upon clicking 
"Play":

[image]

The cloth correctly collides with the Suzanne mesh, as desired, though it slows down a bit. :)